# silverlight datapager and stored procedure

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Is there a way using standard datapager (bound to DomainDataSource) on the server side get the current page (so that to pass it to stored procedure)? Silverlight 4.0, 2010 aprils toolkit, ria service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one: in your `LinqToEntitiesDomainService` class override `public override 
System.Collections.IEnumerable Query(QueryDescription queryDescription, out IEnumerable<ValidationResult> validationErrors, out int totalCount)`
Then extract take and skip from `queryDescription.Query.ToString()` and return `this.ObjectContext.YourStoredProcedure(with paging params)`. 
However, you'll have to handle sorting manually too (sigh).